# iOS: app to maintain/restore wifi connections?

Tags: ios, automation, ipad-app, wifi

At work, my department is rolling out iPads for use in classrooms. Problem: they have to use our "guest" WiFi network because our IS department won't support putting them on the internal network for at least a year. I can set up accounts on the guest network, but they use Cisco access points that require the user to manually enter a username and password each time they connect. We can log the devices in every morning, but if they sit idle for over some small amount of time (seems to be 30 minutes) they auto-log-off and iOS is not smart enough to log in automatically, or even remember the username and password. You have to type them each time. That's a lot to expect a student to do.

Is anyone familiar with an iOS app that does the same thing as the StayAlive configuration parameter of ssh--that is, occasionally send a network packet to keep the connection from timing out?

If you set up mail on the device, it checks often enough to keep the connection up, but we can't do that for student-used devices.

If not, does anyone know of one that adds the functionality of Android's Connection Optimizer to ioS--that is, remembering passwords and auto-entering them and completing Wifi access point logon forms after the first (manual) login?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Skype iOS app uses the VOIP service in iOS which maintains a constant connection even when the device is idle to receive Skype calls. Alternatively, the Facebook and Facebook Messenger apps *mis*use this service for the same effect. Any of these apps will maintain a connection to the network even when backgrounded.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, we can't have any of these apps on the corporate iPads--one thing we have to do (that I didn't mention in the question) is lock down the tablets to block communications. +1, though.